# double buffered in c#

Tags: c#, panel, doublebuffered

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I double buffer a Panel in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818415/how-do-i-double-buffer-a-panel-in-c)
>   [c# panel for drawing graphics and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305011/c-panel-for-drawing-graphics-and-scrolling)

I draw a bitmap on a panel, i use zooming on the same panel. While zooming the panel is continuously flickering. Why do not panel have the DoubleBuffered property?

Code:

```
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(panel.Handle);
                if (newImage == true)
                {
                    g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                    newImage = false;
                }

                g.DrawImage(bmp, hOffset, vOffset);
                g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Check the accepted answer here for a better option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering

Comment: can you write your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics
```

I am a game developer.In games we first draw all objects in a backbuffer and then copy or flip it to frontbuffer.You can use

```
System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics
```

as backbuffer and render it to graphics object.

```
System.Drawing.Graphics
```

for example:

```
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext dc = new BufferedGraphicsContext();
        BufferedGraphics backbuffer = dc.Allocate(g, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), g.VisibleClipBounds.Size.ToSize()));
        backbuffer.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(@"c:\test.jpg"), new Point(10, 10));
        backbuffer.Render(g);
```

Comment: I get an error message **Not enough storage is available to process this command**

Answer (score 1):

Add this code inside the constructor

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |ControlStyles.UserPaint |ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
```

Comment: Inside of *which* constructor? Double-buffering the form isn't going to have any effect on flicker in a panel control on that form. You'll have to subclass the `Panel` class and place this code in the constructor for your custom class. Absent more information, this isn't a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you painting the bitmap?

If not in the `Paint` event or `OnPaint` override, then it is wrong.

To answer your question, only forms have the `DoubleBuffered` property, IIRC.

Comment: I use the Paint event. :). Then how can I avoid the flickering?

Comment: if you do all the drawing on your own you could create your own double buffering, Create a bitmap with the same size as the panel and draw on that one then draw the bitmap to the panel..

Answer (score -2):

Im not 100% sure but cant you activate DoubleBuffered on the form/window instead?

And one tip if your going to use gui with alot of effects i would go with WPF instead of winforms..

You can also override OnPaint and OnPaintBackground..

Comment: Making the form/window double-buffered isn't going to do *anything* for the controls on that form/window. I don't think zooming in on an image counts as "a lot of effects"; WinForms is just fine for this. What is the advantage of overriding `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground` here?

Comment: look at the comment i posted on @leppie post...

Comment: Comments made on another answer do surprisingly little to improve your *own* answer.