# VB.Net Panel Flicker

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have a custom control with line shapes on it. This control is in my panel. Whenever I scroll horizontally on the panel, my control's lines flicker very badly. I've been trying to find a solution to this and have looked at many forums and questions by others, but still haven't seen an answer that works for me.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7569645/495455 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818415/how-do-i-double-buffer-a-panel-in-c

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is winforms as you do not have a wpf tag.  If so - try this - it may help.  This helped with a flickering problem I had.

You can read about it here: http://www.vbmigration.com/detknowledgebase.aspx?Id=692

```
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        'this is magic code that has an enormous positive effect on reducing flickering.
        'don't remove this.
        'found this nugget here: http://www.vbmigration.com/detknowledgebase.aspx?Id=692
        Get
            Dim params As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            params.ExStyle = params.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            Return params
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply! It definitely helped - I would say the flicker reduced by 85%.

Comment: Far out, do you know how old that article is... its 15 years old. A better way is to use DoubleBuffering.

Comment: I've tried DoubleBuffering, it didn't affect my problem.